# WPF - Keep rounded border corners

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

I need to design a form with rounded corners. I have added a border item so I can handle the radius and get the intended result. It gets harder as I want to add a rectangle on the left side of the border item because I cannot get these rounded corners visible anymore. The point then is to add some text in the rectangle shape.

Here is my code :

```
<Window x:Class="WinPE_UI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WinPE_UI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" 
Foreground="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="450" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="800" Background="White" CornerRadius="15" 
Margin="1.375,-1.042,-1.375,1.042">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="449" Margin="0,-1,-1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="799">
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFB41313" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="449" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="105.625"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Do any of you have an idea how to keep the rounded corners with Visual Studio?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution eventually. For those who might be interested, I have drawn a grid on which I applied two borders item sideways.